# How to install Pygame on Python 3.4?

Tags: python, pygame, pip, python-3.4

So I have this little problem. When I try to install Pygame for Python 3.4 I download a .whl (wheel?) file and don't know how to use it. Some guys told me something about pip but don't know how to use/install it.

Comment: I have the same question for my Macbook Pro (OS X Yosemite, version 10.10.5). Which whl can I use to install Pygame with my Python 3.4?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can install the wheel file for Python 3.4 [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame):

First you have to install the wheel package from `pip` then install Pygame.

```sh
pip install wheel

pip install pygame‑1.9.2a0‑cp34‑none‑win_amd64.whl
```

Here's a video to help you install pip on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zPMr0lEMqpo).

Comment: To install pip download and execute the script [here](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py).

Comment: I did not have to install wheel package. Simply running `pip install pygame-1.9.2b1-cp34-cp34m-win32.whl` worked.

Comment: @Antony Newer revisions of Python include `pip` and `wheel` preinstalled which is why you didn't need to install the wheel package ahead of time.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi exactly, Python 3.4 already has pip and wheel. Then why in your answer `pip install wheel`step is needed?

Comment: I know the answer is specific to Python 3.4 but I'm just putting it out there for people who use older version. Personally, I use 2.7 so I would imagine there are others out there.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a great VIDEO tutorial: http://goo.gl/PurJqk (it is on youtube)

This is what I use to install .whl modules to python (I do this in the 64 bit windows cmd):

```
cd "C:\Users\(YOUR USERNAME)\Desktop"
```

(assuming that you have the .whl file on your desktop)

```
C:\Python34\Scripts\pip install filename.whl
```

(where filename.whl is the full name of the .whl file, with the .whl extension)

After that it will install, and you are free to use PyGame!

Answer (score 3):

14 y/o? Good for you! You can put the file into your `python/scripts` folder and run `pip install *file*` (where `*file*` is your filename).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [link](https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/downloads) to download pygame for different versions of Python, up to Python 3.4 in 32 bit and 64 bit.

To test if it installed properly, open your python shell and type in this code:

```
import pygame
```

Please note that these are not official binaries and you are basically trusting a third-party to compile and provide the binary for you.

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1**

If you have not got python version 3.4.2, then you must uninstall your current version of python (or don't if you don't even have python).

**Step 2**

Then download and install python 3.4.2 from http://filehippo.com/download_python/58901/ .

**Step 3**

Follow the instructions and wait until it is ready for use.

**Step 4**

Now download the 'pygame-1.9.2a0-cp34-none-win32.whl' file from [http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame) and copy it into C:\Python34\Scripts .

**Step 5**

In C:\Python34\Scripts hold the shift key and right click. Click on 'Open new command window here'.

**Step 6**

In the command window you have opened, type in:

```
pip3 install pygame-1.9.2a0-cp34-none-win32.whl
```

It will say something like:

```
Unpacking C:\Python34\Scripts\pygame-1.9.2a0-cp34-none-win32.whl 
Installing collected packages: pygame 
Successfully installed pygame 
Cleaning up...
```

And it will then just say C:\Python34\Scripts>, which means that pygame has now been installed!

**Step 7**

Go to the Python 3.4.2 Shell, and type in:

```
import pygame
```

- if there is an error, pygame didn't install properly, otherwise, congratulations!
  You can then:

  import pygame.examples.aliens as game
- and then on the next line type in:

  game.main()
- to see a professional pygame example.

*For more information, visit my website at:
https://ronaldobutrus.github.io/Site3/index.html*

Good Luck! :)

Answer (score 1):

https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/downloads

"pygame-1.9.2a0-hg_5974ff8dae3c+.win32-py3.4.msi"

This is the package you want, RedNax said this but did not point out the exact package.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer doesn't work for me on Windows 10 Pro N x64.

What did work was installing the win32.whl instead of amd64. I put this in my Python3.4\Scripts folder where pip is and ran

```
pip install pygame-1.9.2a0-cp34-none-win32.whl
```

This should work for others using a similar configuration.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, you need to make sure of two things:
1)  Both Python and Pygame should be 32 bit - not either or both being 64 bit.
2)  Both Python and Pygame should be compatible for the same version.

You may be able to get the 64 bit version to work, but not all packages have migrated to 64 bit and the small performance improvement isn't worth the frustration of trying to get it to work.
I also found the latest 32 bit Pygame (as of Feb. 5th, 2016) seems to work well with 32 bit Python 3.4.4.
I installed 32 bit python-3.4.4.msi on Windows 10 from my downloads folder to the folder C:\Python34.
Within the Python34 folder, I created a folder called "Project Directory".
In it, I placed "pygame-1.9.2a0-hg_ea3b3bb8714a.win32-py3.4.msi" which I think I got from https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/downloads.  Double-clicked on it.  Worked the first time.
I had also installed "Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 with Update 1."
No idea if this helped solve the problem, but this MVSC package installs a lot of DLLs.  It takes quite a while to get MVSC installed.
But - I now have Pygame working on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

For linux if you root user then copy paste this into terminal

```
apt-get install python3-dev mercurial
apt-get install libsdl-image1.2-dev libsdl2-dev libsdl-ttf2.0-dev
apt-get install libsdl-mixer1.2-dev libportmidi-dev
apt-get install python-numpy
pip3 install --user hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame
```

If you not root user then use sudo before start every-line.