# How do I install Pygame for Python 3.4.3 on a Windows 7 32-bit computer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pip, 32-bit

I am trying to install Pygame, but I am very confused. On the pygame.org website, there is no version for 3.4, and when I download the correct file from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame I get a .whl file. Upon further investigation, I've come across another question like this: [How to install PyGame on Python 3.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28127730/how-to-install-pygame-on-python-3-4)

But when I try to run

```
pip install wheel
pip install pygame-1.9.2a0-cp34-none-win32.whl
```

I get an error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

And it highlights the "install" part of the code.
Help?

Comment: Yep, sorry, forgot that part. Still get SyntaxError...

Comment: Are you entering the pip commands *within the Python console*?

Comment: I have tried doing it in the shell and a file

Comment: That's a Python error message, though.  `pip` needs to be run from the shell.  (I don't know much about windows so I can't be of help on that side, but it definitely won't work from within Python.)

Comment: I believe you should be using `pip3 install wheel pygame-1.9.2a0-cp34-none-win32.whl`

Comment: I have run it in the shell, command line, and from a file, and it still wont work

Comment: I still get SyntaxError: invalid syntax when I run that, and it highlights "install"

Comment: Try `py -m pip install wheel pygame-1.9.2a0-cp34-none-win32.whl` in your command prompt

Comment: @pythonnoob: one more time for good luck.   *If you are seeing the error message starting `SyntaxError:`, you are doing it from within the Python console.*  That will never work.  Stop doing it!  Try it from within the shell, and edit your question to include a copy-paste of *that* error message.

Comment: @DSM Careful with the use of "shell", lots of people use that terminology for the python interpreter

Comment: I am doing it from the shell! I have tried the command prompt, the python command line, the shell, and from a file!!

Comment: @wilbur I still get the same error

Comment: Also, by shell I mean the window that doesnt look like the command prompt (like on linux), I mean the window that opens with the menus etc

Comment: You need to run those commands *from the command prompt*. As has been said, you may need to use something like `pip3 install...` or `py -3 -m pip install...` if you have version of Python 2 installed. See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27885397/how-do-i-install-a-python-package-with-a-whl-file).

Comment: the python command line, or just the CMD?

Comment: Just regular cmd, something like `c:\>pip install wheel pygame-...`

Comment: "pip" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: by the way, the file is in my downloads folder, does this help?

Comment: If `pip` is not recognised, it is because it isn't on your PATH. It should be in the `Scripts` subfolder of wherever your Python 3.4 is installed (perhaps `C:\Python34\Scripts\pip.exe`). You'll have to use the fully-qualified path for pip from the cmd prompt: `C:\Python34\Scripts\pip.exe install...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to the pygame bitbucket https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/downloads
there is a .msi for 32bit Python 3.4 pygame.