# Install Pygame for Python 3.4 on Windows

Tags: python, windows, pygame, pythonpath, liclipse

I have installed Pygame with the file pygame-1.9.2a0.win32-py3.4.msi in the folder C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\Include (Python 3.4) on my Windows 7 OS.  When I try to import it using `import pygame` it shows the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
     import pygame
ImportError: No module named 'pygame'
```

When I use LiClipse and include the folder C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\Include in the pythonpath under External Libraries, there is no error message for `import pygame` anymore, but when I use `pygame.init()` I get the following error message

```
pygame.init()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'init'
```

Did I install it into the correct folder, have I set the right folder in LiClipse (or should I have to set a folder in the first place), and what can I do to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried doing pip install? This link might explain what you need to do.

[How to install PyGame on Python 3.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28127730/how-to-install-pygame-on-python-3-4#)