# 'ImportError: DLL load failed:' in pygame module

Tags: python

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
import pygame
 File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\pygame\__init__.py", line 127, in <module>
   from pygame.base import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: Check the way you installed pygame.

Comment: tell me how to install pygame.............i am using pygame-1.9.1.win32-py2.7.......should i have to install it in  the same folder as python????

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the version of PyGame you're using matches the version of Python you're using!

Comment: No, I mean that if you're using PyGame for Python 2.6 however you're using Python 2.5 then the PyGame PYD won't be able to find Python, just check if that is correct too!

Answer (score 0):

You have not installed Pygame correctly or not in the correct directory/file. What python version do you use and is your computer 32/64 bit?
Thx

Comment: am using python3.5 and my lappy using 64bit

Answer (score 0):

This is a late answer, but may be it helps someone.

The pygame binary you use should be built for the Python version you have in your system.

In your case, you seem to have 32-bit Python3.5.
There is no official pygame binary for Python3.5 yet. But unofficial binaries are available [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame).

Download `pygame-1.9.2b1-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl` from the link (this is the 32-bit version for 32-bit Python3.5), and install it using `pip`.
Example: `cd` to the folder where you downloaded the .whl file, and run `C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32\Scripts\pip install pygame-1.9.2b1-cp35-cp35m-win32.whl`

**Note:**
`pip` may not play well when the python install directory has spaces. So please install python in a path without spaces. For example, `C:\Python35-32` instead of `C:\Program Files (x86)\Python35-32`.

Also, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29569347/3559967) in case you need more info on installing .whl files.