# ImportError when changing Python interpreter

Tags: python

I have been using PyCharm on Ubuntu to run some Python code, where in `Edit Configurations` I specified the interpreter path as `/usr/bin/python2.7`. The code uses the `pygame` module, and so to install this, I also ran `sudo pip install pygame`. Then I used `import pygame` in my Python script, and the file ran ok.

However, I now want to use Python 3.4. So, in PyCharm, I specified the interpreter path to be `/usr/bin/python3.4`. However, when I run the same file, I now get the error: `ImportError: No module named 'pygame'`.

Can somebody explain why this is happening? How can I get my Python 3.4 interpreter to find Pygame?

Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to reinstall pygame for 3.4: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28127730/how-to-install-pygame-on-python-3-4

Answer (score 2):

Each python installation has a separate set of libraries. Your python 3 does not know about Python 2 and its libraries. It seems the default `pip` command calls the python2 pip script. Run again the `pip install`, but with the python3 pip (look for it in your python3 folder, it is probably named `pip3`)

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, different Python installations will maintain their own independent set of libraries. Bear in mind that you can install packages from the same window that you use to change the interpreter in PyCharm for a project. You might find that more convenient if you're switching between interpreters.

You just click the green 'plus' icon to do so:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

pygame has different releases for each version of Python.

As you have the Python 2.7 module and want to upgrade to Python 3.4, you'll need to reinstall pygame using Python 3.4 instead, you can using `pip` again or you can download files from here: http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml.